# can't join 2 tables getting type exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Try to learn asp.net mvc with ef6.
I am joining 2 tables currently as follows:

```
var  userToTransports = db.UserToTransports.Include(u => u.Transport).Include(u => u.User).Include(u => u.User1)

               
                .Where(u => u.User.Login.Equals(user))
                 .Join(
                db.Insurences,
                p => p.Transport_id, // свойство-селектор объекта из первого набора
                c => c.Transport_id, // свойство-селектор объекта из первого набора
                (p, c) => new  { Amount=c.Amount }


                 );
```

But When I run my app I am getting an error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`1[System.Decimal]] ``, but this dictionary requires a model item of type `` System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TransportRegistration.UserToTransport] ``.

My view looks like this currently

```
@model IEnumerable<TransportRegistration.UserToTransport>



@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

Without join statement everythin works fine. What can I do about it?
Also will add my model code here if it wil help

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace TransportRegistration
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    public partial class UserToTransport
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Владелец")]

        public int Owner_id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Транспортное средство")]

        public int Transport_id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Право управления")]

        public int Driver_id { get; set; }
    
        public virtual Transport Transport { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public virtual User User1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Well. I also tryed to add a get and set for insurence table inmodel it didn't help either

Comment: error message is self-explained. what is type of your variable `userToTransports` ?

Comment: Greate. That I understud. But how can I get that result from an other table that is Joined? As I can see it is returning a list.

Comment: `(p, c) => new {...}` here you can put everything that you need to return. a bit unclear what you want in result

Comment: That what I didn't get. I want to return all columns of Insurence table and UserToTransport table

Comment: then just `(p, c) => new {UserToTransport = p, Insurence = c}`

Comment: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[TransportRegistration.UserToTransport,TransportRegistration.Insurence]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TransportRegistration.UserToTransport]'.

Comment: You should also update model in your view as now it only expect collection of `UserToTransport`. As you said you need `all columns of Insurence table and UserToTransport table` then you need to change your view model to support it

Comment: Could you please give me an example how to change it?

Answer (score 0):

Your view's model is expecting a collection of UserToTransport entities.

However, your populating statement:

```
var  userToTransports = db.UserToTransports.Include(u => u.Transport).Include(u => u.User).Include(u => u.User1)
            .Where(u => u.User.Login.Equals(user))
             .Join(
            db.Insurences,
            p => p.Transport_id, 
            c => c.Transport_id, 
            (p, c) => new  { Amount=c.Amount }
             );
```

which can be simplified down to:

```
var  userToTransports = db.UserToTransports
    .Where(u => u.User.Login.Equals(user))
    .Join(db.Insurences,
        p => p.Transport_id, 
        c => c.Transport_id, 
        (p, c) => new  { Amount = c.Amount });
```

is generating a set of anonymous types /w the `decimal` Amount values from the Insurances associated with all of the UserToTransport records. Effectively "Select all amounts from Insurances associated with the UserToTransports"

So either your view is expecting the wrong data, or your controller is loading the wrong data. Do you want to display UserToTransports, or do you want to display some form of data from the associated Insurance records?

Given the apparent relationships I would suspect that the explicit join may be unnecessary that you can access Insurances through the `UserToTransport.Transport` reference, I.e.:

```
var amounts = db.UserToTransport
    .SelectMany(u => u.Transport.Insurances.Select(i => new {Amount = i.Amount }));
```

Though I suspect that's not really what you're after.

If you want to be displaying UserToTransport details along with their associated Insurance figures then I strongly recommend looking into projecting view models rather than trying to pass entities to the view. For example if you want to display some information about the UserToTransport, their associated user, transport, and a sum of their insurances:

```
[Serializable]
public class UserToTransportViewModel
{
    public int UserToTransportId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string TransportName { get; set; }
    public decimal InsuranceTotal { get; set; } 
}
```

then in your view:

```
@model IEnumerable<UserToTransportViewModel>
```

and to populate:

```
var viewModels = db.UserToTransports
    .Select(u => new UserToTransportViewModel
    {
        UserToTransportId == u.UserToTransportId,
        Name = u.User.Name,
        TransportName = u.Transport.Name,
        InsuranceTotal = u.Transport.Insurances.Sum(i => i.Amount)
    }).ToList();
return View(viewModels);
```

Obviously the composition of the view model would depend entirely on what your view wants to display and your specific schema, but it will result in efficient queries and cut down on sending more detail than the view needs.